# GROUP_CONCAT same column with different conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out a query to return a comma separated string from my table. I'm only using one column as reference but I have 2 conditions, I'm not sure how to start the Query to do what i want.

| my_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

Basically I need to have a comma seperated string of Ids that match a particular group ID
so the returned Data should come back as

| ids_with_group_id_of_1 | ids_with_group_id_of_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 3,4 |

Is there any way to have different conditions for group_concat ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with conditional aggregation

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN group_id = 1 THEN my_id END) ids_with_group_id_of_1,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN group_id = 2 THEN my_id END) ids_with_group_id_of_2
FROM tablename
WHERE group_id IN (1, 2)
```

Remove the `WHERE` clause if `1` and `2` are the only values of `group_id`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3931711b9bcf2a80255f918a3c2a50ac).